# Wrong version of swift

Tags: xcode, swift

How can I run swift 2.1?

I have Xcode 7.0.1 installed but when I run swift in the terminal,
I getting version 2.0.

```
> swift -v

Apple Swift version 2.0 (swiftlang-700.0.59 clang-700.0.72)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/lldb "--repl=-target     x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0 -enable-objc-interop -sdk            
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -color-diagnostics"
Welcome to Apple Swift version 2.0 (700.0.59 700.0.72). Type :help for assistance.
```

I thought Xcode7 included swift 2.1

Comment: XCode 7.1 should include Swift 2.1.

Answer (score 3):

See the [Wikipedia article on Xcode § Toolchain Versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Toolchain_versions).

In the table, it says that Xcode 7.0 includes Swift 2.0.

The first version of Xcode to include Swift 2.1 is version 7.1.

You will have to update Xcode from the App Store.